# I'm new in firebase realtime database and I need some help in the code

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

this is my code, and there is a problem in if statment, I need to make query about the user name if exist and then make a query to check if the user enter the password right or no

```
Query checkUser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").orderByChild("fName").equalTo(inputName);
                checkUser.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        if(snapshot.exists()){

                            eName.setError(null);
                            eName.setEnabled(true);


                          
                               if(snapshot.child(inputName).child("pass").getValue().equals(inputPassword)) {
                                   ePassword.setError(null);
                                   ePassword.setEnabled(true);

                                   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login was successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomePage.class);
                                   startActivity(intent);

                                   } else {
                                   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Incorrect Password! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                   }
                        }

                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Incorrect Username! ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }
```

[this is my screenshot for database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrCc0.png)

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: can you show database single user object?

Comment: even if I entered the password correctly it shows me that the password is incorrect, in the second if statement it's always ,if the password correct or no , its return the Toast that the passwordis in correct

Comment: Can you edit your question with the database User table

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo can you check now please

Comment: The code looks fine, But please try by giving the static inputName and inputPassword and attach debugger to find what is happening actually.

Comment: @DeepakShukla it's not valid code because it retrieves the array of document snapshot and he is comparing one document so field is null

Comment: @Ashish so what i have to do ?

Comment: @HamzehGhanem see my answer and check what output you get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your getting list of datasnapshot. So just retrieve the data snapshot from it and compare password.

```
checkUser.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot userSnapShot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            if(userSnapShot.child("pass").getValue(String.class).equals(inputPassword)) {
                Log.e("password", "Valid");
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Incorrect Password! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // Getting Post failed, log a message
        Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        // ...
    }
});
```